# How can I highlight DataGrid's ColumnHeader and RowHeader, when a cell is Selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I microsof Excel, when a cell or a group of cells are selected, colums' headers and the rows' headers will be highlighted. How can I implement a similar feature in a wpd DataGrid?

I think I should handle `DataGrid.SelectionChanged` event, but I have no idea how I can proceed. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way to do this is using SelectedCellsChanged event.

Check my example:

XAML code:

```
 <DataGrid Name="myData"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  SelectionMode="Extended"
                  SelectionUnit="Cell"                  
                  SelectedCellsChanged="myData_SelectedCellsChanged"                  
                  />
```

Code-behind:

```
private void myData_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
            foreach (var item in myData.Columns)
            {
                item.HeaderStyle = null;
            }

            if (myData.SelectedCells != null && myData.SelectedCells.Count != 0)
            {
                Style styleSelected = new Style();
                styleSelected.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange)));

                foreach (var item in myData.SelectedCells)
                {
                    item.Column.HeaderStyle = styleSelected;
                }
            }
  }
```

You can also set Border.BorderBrushProperty and Border.BorderThicknessProperty in styleSelected if you want vertical line between columns.